# Python multiprocessing: parsing, editing, and writing long series of csv files

Tags: python-2.7, csv, multiprocessing

I have a very long series of similar cvs files (14Gb altogether). I need to open each file, replace certain characters, and write the fixed version to a new file.    I want to use the processing power of my multicore computer. I tried with mp.Pools and with mp.Process/mp.Queue. The pool version works, but the queue approach produces this error:

`IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x0000000002775A90>'`

This is a simplified version of my Pool code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
def fixer(a_file):
    lines = []
    opened_file = open(a_file)
    for each_line in opened_file:
        lines.append(each_line.replace('mad', 'rational'))
    opened_file.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
    #some pandas magics here
    df.to_csv(a_file[:-4] + '_fixed.csv')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_path = os.getcwd()
    my_files = list(os.walk(my_path))[0][2] #I just get the list of file names here
    processors = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = processors) # I set as many processes as processors my computer has.
    pool.map(fixer, my_files)
```

And this is the one for the Queue approach:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
def fixer(a_file):
    lines = []
    opened_file = open(a_file)
    for each_line in opened_file:
        lines.append(each_line.replace('mad', 'rational'))
    opened_file.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
    #some pandas magics here
    df.to_csv(a_file[:-4] + '_fixed.csv')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_path = os.getcwd()
    my_files = list(os.walk(my_path))[0][2] #I just get the list of file names here
    processors = mp.cpu_count()
    queue = mp.Queue()
    for each_file in my_files:
        queue.put(each_file)
    processes = [mp.Process(target = fixer, args=(queue,)) for core in range(processors)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

I will appreciate if you can provide an example to make the Queue version to work. In a second processing step, before the files are written, I need the processors to get an intermediate result and do some calculations. This is the reason why I need the queues.

Comment: OK, I found what was happening. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the Queue script is that I was not getting the next element in the Queue, but passing the whole Queue to the fixer function. This problem is solved by assigning the value of `queue.get()` to a variable in the fixer function:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
def fixer(a_queue):
    a_file = a_queue.get()
    lines = []
    opened_file = open(a_file)
    for each_line in opened_file:
        lines.append(each_line.replace('mad', 'rational'))
    opened_file.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
    #some pandas magics here
    df.to_csv(a_file[:-4] + '_fixed.csv')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_path = os.getcwd()
    my_files = list(os.walk(my_path))[0][2] #I just get the list of file names here
    processors = mp.cpu_count()
    queue = mp.Queue()
    for each_file in my_files:
        queue.put(each_file)
    processes = [mp.Process(target = fixer, args=(queue,)) for core in range(processors)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: Can someone explain why you need to include a `,` after passing the `Queue` when defining the `args` of the `mp.Process`?

Comment: that's because the `args` parameter must receive a tuple as argument, and when a tuple in python has only one element, it must have a `,` after that element. More info in section 5.3 of [python's data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).